# Newbie - Yii2: Cannot show data on View from Controller

Tags: php, yii2

New to Yii2 and learn some demo from tutorials, try to copy code and use on my own demo but seem to fail to work. Here is the code:

tutorial - Controller:

```
namespace app\controllers;
use yii\web\Controller;

use app\models\Article;
use Yii;

class ArticleController extends Controller{

    public function actionIndex(){

        $article = Article::find();

        //echo $article->count();

        $pagination = new \yii\data\Pagination(['totalCount'=>$article->count(), 'pageSize'=>3]);
        $data = $article->offset($pagination->offset)->limit($pagination->limit)->all();
        //print_r($data);

        return $this->render('index',['data' => $data, 'pagination' => $pagination]);
    }
```

tutorial - View:

```
<?php

    use yii\helpers\Url;

?>
<p style = "text-align:right">
    <a href="<?=Url::to(['add'])?>" class="btn btn-primary">ADD</a>
</p>


<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>id</th><th>Title</th><th>Count</th><th>Status</th><th>Update Time</th><th>By</th>
    </tr>
    <?php print_r($data); foreach($data as $v){?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$v->id?></td><td><?=$v->title?></td><td><?=$v->count?></td><td><?=($v->status == '1' ? 'Y' :'N')?></td>
        <td><?=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$v->update_date)?></td>
        <td><a href="<?=Url::to(['edit', 'id'=>$v->id])?>">Edit</a> | <a href="<?=Url::to(['delete','id'=>$v->id])?>">Del</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php }?>
</table>

<div style="float:right">
    <?=\yii\widgets\LinkPager::widget([
        'pagination' => $pagination,
        'options' =>[
            'class' =>'pagination',
            ],
        ])
    ?>
</div>
```

Use print_r($data), and it shows below:

```
Array ( [0] => app\models\Article Object ( [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [id] => 1 [flag] => 0 [title] => 13123OOOO [description] => tttt1 [content] => tstsets 
[count] => 1 [status] => 1 [update_date] => 1462291610 [date] => 0 ) [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [id] => 1 [flag] => 0 [title] => 13123OOOO 
[description] => tttt1 [content] => tstsets [count] => 1 [status] => 1 [update_date] => 1462291610 [date] => 0 ) [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( ) 
[_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) 
[_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) )
```

But on my own code:
Controller:

```
namespace app\controllers;
use yii\web\Controller;

use app\models\Inventory;

class InventoryController extends Controller{

    public function actionIndex(){

        //$inventory = new Inventory();
        $inventory = Inventory::find()->asArray()->all();
        print_r($inventory);

        return $this->renderpartial('index',['inventory' => $inventory]);
    }
```

View:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;

echo "<br>";
print_r($inventory);
?>
<h2>Inventory Status</h2>
<table class = "table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th><th>Model</th><th>Office</th><th>Warehouse</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <?php foreach($inventory as $item){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$item->id ?></td><td><?=$item->name ?></td><td><?=$item->office ?></td><td><?=$item->warehouse ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php }?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>?<td>Apple</td><td>1</td><td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My print_r($inventory) is like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Apple [office] => 1 [warehouse] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => Android [office] => 2 [warehouse] => 1 ) )
```

And use foreach(){} but cannot show any data, how to fix that?

Comment: Before discover the hot water or invent the weel another time  I suggest  you of use Gii for generating default code crud MVC and  see the result  ..avoiding so a lot of work    http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-gii.html

Comment: I want to use foreach() instead of using Gridview on my demo, from the most understandable what I have learned, the Gii is using many built-in widgets that not my prefer so far.

Comment: you are getting data `asArray()` and accessing them as object( `$item->id` ) ! try removing the `->asArray()` part from you controller. if that doesn't work, include your error message you are getting on the question.

Comment: solved, just need to add find()->all() on the controller.

Answer (score 0):

In your code  you have a nested tr (try removing)

```
<table class = "table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th><th>Model</th><th>Office</th><th>Warehouse</th>
    </tr>

         <?php foreach($inventory as $item){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$item['id'] ?></td><td><?=$item['name'] ?></td><td><?=$item['office'] ?></td><td><?=$item['warehouse'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php }?>

    <tr>
        <td>?<td>Apple</td><td>1</td><td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: hi, removed <tr> and same issue, any other idea you think my code is wrong?

Comment: If you get the data by asArray then try accessing like an array and not like an object .. i have update the answer